# '80s Aquaman tv-series?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

Back in the good old days of [Automan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automan), [The Greatest American Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greatest_American_Hero) and [Manimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manimal), I remember watching another (probably) tv-series featuring a sort of Aquaman. I think I watched just a few episodes of this series, maybe only the pilot, so I just remember this man with webbed hands and feet, trapped in some sort of lab, saying he was cold (or warm?) because he was mutating.

Can someone help me in identifying this series and, maybe most important, tell me if it's worth watching today?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can stretch '80s to include 1977-78 this sounds like [Man From Atlantis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_from_Atlantis), starring Patrick Duffy of Dallas fame.

It was a very short run series after some TV movies about the character.

As for your last question - I suspect not.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you! I recognize the [synthesized music](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doAuUuWsh1E#t=10m43s)!